# Calling object in a 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array like...

```
outerArray = [
    middleArray1 = [
        innerArray1 = ['data'],
        innerArray2 = ['more data']
    ],
    middleArray2 = [
         ...more stuff...
    ]
];
```

How can I access one of the inner arrays in javascript?

Is it `outerArray.middleArray1.innerArray1` ?

Comment: In your case its actually just `innerArray1`. But that's because your definition is weird (you are assigning inside your array definition).

Comment: Your "thing" is actually a 3D array, if it is even one, because it looks more like an object

Comment: in your example you can access in your "middle array" with an index, like outerArray[0] .... outerArray[N-1], but your syntax is ... weird actually

Comment: You can't access arrays by properties. Use `[]` brackets to access data. Do `console.log(outerArray);` and look at the indices of each level.

Comment: Is this actually how you've defined your data? If so, you should seriously reconsider. If you're instead trying to simply describe your array structure using this format, have a look at how to create a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit the question with real code. This will be much more likely to produce a helpful answer to your question.

Comment: Pretty much you should just get rid of the naming/assigning portion within the array(s) (`middleArray1 = ...`) as it's going to just end in indexes anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't really told us what you are trying to do here, but I suspect you are mixing up objects, which use `{}` and have property access like `outerArray.middleArray1`, and arrays which are defined with `[]` and accessed by index: `outerArray[0]`.

You example sort of works because assignments return the assigned value. This means something like:

```
middleArray1 = [
    innerArray1 = ['data'],
    innerArray2 = ['more data']
]
```

is the same as:

```
middleArray1 = [['data'],['more data']]
```

with the side effect that `innerArray1` and `innerArray2` get defined as global variables. For example:

```js
outerArray = [
    middleArray1 = [
        innerArray1 = ['data'],
        innerArray2 = ['more data']
    ],
    middleArray2 = [
        ' ...more stuff...'
    ]
];

// log global variable innerArray1 (probably not what you want)
console.log(innerArray1)

// access ith index:
console.log(outerArray[0][0])
```

This is almost certainly not what you want. If you want to access data with properties like `outerArray.middleArray1`, you need to define an object. For example:

```js
// use {} to define object literal
outerArray = {
        middleArray1: {
            innerArray1: 'data',
            innerArray2: 'more data',
        },
        middleArray2: ' ...more stuff...'
 };
 
 // now access by property name
 console.log(outerArray.middleArray1.innerArray1)
```

Of course, you probably want to use a better naming convention for your properties…

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I need! Yeah I was mixing up objects like you said.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that's very weird way of creating nested arrays as you may not be able to access array elements with array names like `'middleArray1'`, I tried that but it doesn't work. After all, the array will be available in this format only...

```
outerArray = [
    [
        ['data'],
        ['more data']
    ],
    [
         ...more stuff...
    ]
];
```

You could still access inner elements as `outerArray[0][0]` (innerArray1) or also

`outerArray[0][0][0]` (1st element of innerArray1)

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on what [`deadman`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9776732/dedman) said.

Let's break down your multi-dimensional array into levels.

1. `middleArray` is `Level 1`
2. `middleArray -> innerArray1` is `Level 2`
3. `middleArray -> innerArray1 -> value` is `Level 3`

To access `data` for example, you will have 3 levels meaning 3 `[]` brackets.

Example:

---

`var data = outerArray[0][0][0]` will output `data`.

`var moreData = outArray[0][0][1]` will output `more data`.

---

`outerArray[0]` accesses the first array on `Level 1` which is `middleArray1`.

`outerArray[1]` accesses the second array on `Level 1` which is `middleArray2`.

`outerArray[0][0]` accesses the first array on `Level 2` which is `innerArray1`.

and so on.

---

Read over [`Creating a Multidimensional Array`](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-cookbook/9781449390211/ch05s03.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration is a bit strange as noted by TiiJ7.  Typically an array of arrays would look more like this:

```
const outerArray = [
    [
        [data],
        [moredata]
    ],
    [
        // more stuff
    ]
]
```

And you would call each item by its index like outerArray[0][0][0]

It looks like what you really want is an object.

```
const dataObj = {
    middleObj1: {
        innerObj1: [data],
        innerObj2: [moredata]
    },
    middleObj2: {
        // more stuff
    }
}
```

This one can be called by key instead of index alone.  That is, you can either choose to use dataObj['middleObj1']['innerObj1'][0] or dataObj.middleObj1.innerObj1[0]

Notice how I'm still ending it with an index in both cases.  That's because I kept your innermost array in my example.  You can nest arrays within objects.  In fact arrays ARE a special type of object in JavaScript.  JavaScript just uses generic objects instead of multi-dimensional Arrays.